# Creating object with constant parameters from stream

Tags: c++

let us assume I have a class with

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test{
    public:
        friend istream& operator >> (istream& input, Test& test){
            input >> test.dummy;
            return input;
        };
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& output, Test& test){
            output << test.dummy << endl;
            return output;
        };
    private:
        const int dummy;
}
```

This does not work because dummy is constant. Is there a way to load from file and recreate an object with parameters which are constant?

Comment: May be delete the previous object. create another object and make the previous one point to it.

Comment: The ostream operator should take a `Test const&` since you don't change the test class inside it.

Comment: Can you add some explanation about why `dummy` is `const` and what you're using the `operator>>` for in you code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The "I really, really need this" way

Use const_cast. Usually you use it for objects that outside look like if they are constant, but internally they do need to update state every now and then. Using it for reading from stream is a little confusing, to say the least.

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream& input, Test& test){
    input >> const_cast<int&>(test.dummy);
    return input;
};
```

### The recommended way

Ditch stream operator, use a factory function.

```
static Test fromStream(istream& input) {
    int dummy;
    input >> dummy;
    return Test(dummy);
}
```

### The best way

Ditch const. Instead, pass your entire object as const if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Streams are something you read from, they are not factories or something like that.

You have several choices, though:

- Read from the stream to a non-`const`, and then use that to initialize your `const` object
- You can make `dummy` non-`const`, initialize your object as *unread*, and then read into `dummy`; then you can pass outside only `const&` to `dummy`

Comment: The second suggestion is terrible.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Why?

Comment: Because constructing objects in invalid state is a common source of problems and goes against modern C++ best practices.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz You right, but I've not said *invalid*; I was meaning something along the line of `bool read = false;` :) From the OP code, I can't know how `Test` will be used. Test may signal another thread when read, or send a message, or simply change its internal state. Though, I have to admit I've been **not very clear**, so -1 is welcome

Answer (score 2):

You declared `dummy` `const`, so obviously mutating it during the lifetime of `Test` would break the contract about `const`.

This is what `operator>>` is doing at the moment and the compiler is helpfully trying to prevent you from breaking that contract.

#### Does `operator>>` actually do the *initialization* of `Test`?

If `operator>>` should only do the initialization, not overwriting, of `Test`, then you should turn `operator>>` into a factory function, as demonstrated in gwiazdorrr's "recommended way".

If, on the other hand, `operator>>` should overwrite `Test`, then you're breaking the contract about the `const`ness of `dummy`, and that's just bad. Therefore, `dummy` should be non-`const`.

#### Does `dummy` *really* need to be `const`?

You could simply enforce the immutability of `dummy` through the interface of `Test`. Though in this case it could still be mutated *inside* the class, which is probably what you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Define a `Dummy` class:

```
class Dummy {
public:
    Dummy() { value = 0; }
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& input, const Dummy& dummy){
        input >> dummy.value;
        return input;
    }
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& output, const Dummy& dummy){
        output << dummy.value << endl;
        return output;
    }
    int getValue() const { return value; }
private:
    mutable int value;
};
```

And use it in `Test`:

```
class Test {
public:
    Test() { cin >> dummy; }
private:
    const Dummy dummy;
};
```

It works as expected.

Comment: @user673679 I see I didn't make myself clear, see the edit.

Comment: I see that mutable does the trick here. This is also a valid possibility.